# PowerBI refresh update notification

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Disclaimer: While I've done a bit of development with PowerBI desktop, I'm new to the Power BI API and Azure apps, so this question is more just trying to figure out what I don't know, and what to research.

I have a report that's not used a whole lot, but needs up-to-date info when it is run. It's currently using imported data sets. I want to see if there's an option besides doing a scheduled refresh every few hours, when it won't be used for a while in between.

I've figured out how to trigger a refresh via a Flow, but is there a way to get the refresh result back to the report?

If my data source takes a minute or two to refresh, the user has no way of knowing when it's updated, and that they need to refresh the report to get the latest data. Is there a way to show a text box visual saying "Please refresh the report" or something like that? How do I get that "last refresh time" back from the workspace when it's been completed?